# React Native Notifee on Android - endless loop of notifications

Tags: android, react-native

I have a problem with Android repeating notifications (used [Notifee](https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/overview) library version `"@notifee/react-native": "^4.1.0"`). The notification is fired many times on some devices and must be killed from app settings. Looks like a never-ending loop of the same notification.
The problem found so far in these 2 situations: 1) the user doesn't use the app for a few days and then opens it (despite we are not scheduling notification in any hook, it's on the button), 2) the user had fly mode at the time of notification.

Notification set with this code:

```
notifee.createTriggerNotification(notification, trigger);
```

trigger:

```
{
    alarmManager: {
      allowWhileIdle: true,
    },
    type: TriggerType.TIMESTAMP,
    timestamp: fireDate,
    repeatFrequency: RepeatFrequency.WEEKLY,
  };
```

notification:

```
{
    title: alertTitle,
    body: alertBody,
    data: userInfo,
    android: {
      channelId,
      importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
      pressAction: {
        id: 'default',
        launchActivity: 'default',
        launchActivityFlags: [AndroidLaunchActivityFlag.SINGLE_TOP],
      },
      smallIcon: 'ic_small_icon',
      largeIcon: 'ic_launcher',
      style: alertBody
        ? {
            type: AndroidStyle.BIGTEXT,
            text: alertBody,
          }
        : undefined,
      showTimestamp: true,
      visibility: AndroidVisibility.PUBLIC,
      sound: 'default',
    },
    ios: {
      sound: 'default',
      foregroundPresentationOptions: {
        sound: true,
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
      },
    },
  };
```

Have you ever noticed similar behavior? Any ideas on what can cause it?

Comment: Please can you show more of your code? I would like to exactly how you define your trigger object

Comment: Hi, I finally solved this issue by updating to the latest version of Notifee 5.3.0, so it was probably the version related problem, not the code itself.